# How can I access a PHP file on a server via Unity for MySQL- database manipulation?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine, ssl

I'm currently developing a login system for an online Unity game. My goal is to have a database on my server and to check if the user is registered. 
I followed this [tutorial](https://appnimiacademy.com/email-authentication-in-unity-with-php-and-mysql-as-backend/), if you need more background information than provided.

I have a PHP script on my server and a database. The PHP script is under the default folder of my web server (purplepandagames.com/httpdocs/auth.php).

```
$hostname = "<localhost:3306>";
$username = "<username>";
$dbname = "<dbName>";
$password = "<password>";

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

To connect to the server I use these values in my PHP script. Is localhost correct? Or is the hostname purplepandagames.com? The database is attached to purplepandagams.com.

In Unity, I have a script called AuthManager, which handles the connection. Here are some parts of the C# script that might be wrong:

```
string authphpurl = "https://purplepandagames.com/auth.php";    //enter the complete URL for auth.php

    IEnumerator PostDataForLogin()
    {     
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("email", emailText.text);
        form.AddField("pwd", passwordText.text);

        var url = authphpurl + "?action=login";

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        Debug.Log("Response:" + www.downloadHandler.text);

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
            responseText.text = www.error;
        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");

            JSONNode jsonNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);
            Debug.Log("success : " + jsonNode["success"]);
            Debug.Log("message : " + jsonNode["msg"]);


            responseText.text = jsonNode["msg"];
        }
     }
```

For simpleJSON I'm using [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON).

If I run the code like this, the error message `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` appears. If I change the authphpurl to only https://purplepandagames.com, there is no feedback and the         `Debug.Log("Response:" + www.downloadHandler.text);` statement just outputs the index.html file.

The website has an SSL certification, this could be a problem.

And in general, is it even a good idea to solve this problem like this? I would encrypt the passwords before uploading to the database. But at the moment I do not understand what prevents other people of being able to manipulate this database as well.

Comment: Did you try calling the URL from browser or any software like Postman? There may be some error in the PHP script or bad server configuraiton, as HTTP 500 is for server error and not client error.

Comment: Yes, if I try to open purplepandagames.com/auth.php in Chrome, HTTP Error 500 appears as well. Here is the full [PHP file](https://hastebin.com/xacadihelo.xml)

Comment: Then the problem is in PHP not Unity. I will try to look at it and fix it.

Comment: Thank you! The server is running PHP-Version 7.2.19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you indicated in the comments, You are using PHP version 7.2.19, and used code that is a bit older. That code uses mysql_ functions, which were deprecated in PHP version 5.5.0 and removed in PHP 7.

I tried to change that code, it worked on my pc ( PHP 7.3, MySQL ) so it should work on your server too.

Please recreate your table ( if possible ) with this code as for some reason tutorial you sent doesn't use Auto Increment and also there is very small place for data to insert ( varchar(20) for password ? )

I have also added mysqli_real_escape_string which is to prevent SQL injection.
I have added sha256 to your passwords as you don't want to save them plain-text.

SQL Table creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    id bigint auto_increment primary key,
    email varchar(256) not null,
    pwd   varchar(256) not null,
    constraint users_so_email_uindex
    unique (email)
);
```

And PHP Code

```php
<?php

//These variable values need to be changed by you before deploying
//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.
$hostname = "your_server";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database_name";


//Connect to your database
$db = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.");

function login($db){
    // Escape string and prevent possible SQL injection
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    // Prepare SQL statement
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=?);
    $statement->bind_param("s", $email);
    $statement->execute();
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
       $hashed_pwd = $row['pwd'];
     }

    if(password_verify($pwd, $hashed_pwd)){
        echo 'User verified successfully!';
    }

    // Close SQL Statement
    $statement->close();

    echo '{"success":false,"msg":"Email and/or Password Invalid"}';
}

function register($db){

    // Escape string and prevent possible SQL injection
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd =  password_hash($_POST['pwd'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // Prepare SQL statement for check existing user
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=?");
    $statement->bind_param("s", $email);
    $statement->execute();

    // Get result
    $results = $statement->get_result();

    // User already exists
    if($results && $results->num_rows > 0) {
        echo '{"success":false,"msg":"Users Exists"}';
        $statement->close();
        return;
    }

    // Close statement for check existing user
    $statement->close();

    // Prepare SQL statement for insertion
    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (email, pwd) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $statement->bind_param("ss", $email, $pwd);

    // Execute insert statement
    if($statement->execute()) {
        echo '{"success":true,"msg":"User registered successfully"}';

        $statement->close();
        return;
    }

    // Something went wrong and user was not registered
    echo '{"success":false,"msg":"Unable to register user"}';
}

function forgot($db){
    echo '{"success":false,"msg":"Feature not yet implemented"}';
}

$action = null;

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
}

if ($action == "login") {
    login($db);
} elseif ($action == "register") {
    register($db);
} elseif ($action == "forgot") {
    forgot($db);
}

$db->close();

exit();
```

**EDIT: ** As suggested in the comments, I have edited the code to go with SQL Statements - Thanks Immorality

```
var url = authphpurl + "?action=login";

List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("email=" + emailText.text + "&pwd=" + passwordText.text));

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, formData);
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

Same snippet can be used for REGISTER

**EDIT :** PHP works, now UNITY. I did not work in unity once, but as I was looking for solution ( Form data not sending to PHP ), I saw this solution. It may help. Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual//UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html

Comment: even though escaping the string helps against SQL injections, it does not prevent it. Prepared statements with Mysqli or PDO are the way to go.

Comment: What you wrote is true. I will edit my answer with use of prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you very much, the connection does work now. I had to change the sizes of email and pwd to 128 because I got specified key was too long. But the registration still fails, it is unable to register new users. The connection stands, the feedback is correct, but the
``` JSONNode jsonNode = 
      SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);`
            Debug.Log("success : " + jsonNode["success"]);
            Debug.Log("message : " + jsonNode["msg"]);
```
returns False and Unable to register user. I tried different lengths.

Comment: So your ``Debug.Log("Response:" + www.downloadHandler.text);`` returns correct JSON but you are not able to parse it? Or did I misunderstood? because my Insomnia is returning correct values ( https://imgur.com/a/SdHMdKO )

Comment: No, just the success feedback is negative. But if it works on your machine, it is likely to be just Unity. [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/0wMHyy2)

Comment: There is possibility that SQL statement is not correct. You may try replacing line 78 in PHP with this: ``echo '{"success":false,"msg":"Unable to register user","code":"'. $db->errno .'"}';`` This will add 'code' to the output and let you know about MySQL Error Code ( If there is problem with SQL, this code may help you getting to the root of problem )

Comment: Thank you, the code is 1048 (Column cannot be null). I think this is caused by not providing an ID?

Comment: Yes. that may be it. ID should have Auto-Incrementing value ( ID will be automatically +1 for each record ). You may try checking all other values (email, pwd) as 'CAN BE NULL' so you see if everything is sent to PHP.

Comment: Both, email and pwd are null values (pwd is the default hash value for null). This shouldn't be, I checked before sending the value of emailText.text and it is the correct mail.
```form.AddField("email", emailText.text); ```
```UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);```

But this statement looks like if its just sending null.

Comment: I have added code snippet to the end of my answer. you can look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198420/discussion-between-maros-d-and-lukas-hertel).